# Query works in shell but not in browser

Tags: django, django-queryset

I have this query in a view:

```
def metas (request, pipol_id):
  pipol = Personas.objects.get(pk=pipol_id).evidencias_set.all().exclude(calidad=1)
  return render_to_response ( 'metas/metas.html', {'pipol': pipol} )
```

When I test this code in shell:

```
pipol_id = u'3'
pipol = Personas.objects.get(pk=pipol_id).evidencias_set.all().exclude(calidad=1)
pipol.count()
Out[8]: 45
pipol = Personas.objects.get(pk=pipol_id).evidencias_set.all()
pipol.count()
Out[10]: 46
```

The query works as expected (I have one `evidencia` with `calidad=1`.

But when I try in my template, I get no data.

This is the `urls.py`:

```
url (r'^(?P<pipol_id>\d+)/$', 'metas'),
```

The url is like this: `http://localhost:8000/metas/3/`.

No errors, just an empty QuerySet. What I'm missing?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: There could be a problem in the template.  Have you set a breakpoint in the view, and seen that `pipol.count()` is 0 when loading the page?

Comment: Did you ever solve this? BECAUSE I RAN INTO IT TODAY.

Answer (score 0):

In your shell your are using `3` for value of `pipol_id` while in browser you are trying with value `1`.

`Personas` object with id `1` may not have anything in `evidencias_set`.

Comment: Actually, no matter what value use, alway get an empty QuerySet. I gonna change the example to reflect this fact.

Comment: Are both using same DB? Any caching? Also check if there are multiple view functions with same name `metas` in views.py.

Comment: Yes, both, the site and shell use the same database in SQLite.